# android - how to make a corner view like this view

Tags: android, android-view, textview

I want to make a corner like the image below :

[image]

I made an image and put it there , it was ok but I can't set the textview , I tried to rotate the textview but it doesn't work

this is my code :

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="100dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:adjustViewBounds="true"
               android:alpha=".7"
               android:src="@drawable/cornerlogo" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="100dp"
              android:layout_height="100dp"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:layout_marginRight="-8dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
              android:gravity="left|top"
              android:inputType="textMultiLine"
              android:rotation="-30"
              android:text="ساعت 8"
              android:textColor="#FC832A"
              android:textSize="11sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I make something like that

Comment: check [this for reference](https://github.com/shts/TriangleLabelView)

Comment: Just add elevation on textview so it will bring it to front you can use FrameLayout instead of Relative Layout

Comment: I tried your code snippet and the textview works just fine. I can see the textview with the rotation. Are you sure the issue is with this code snippet. Could you share the entire xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable of layer-list following xml should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="100%"
            android:pivotY="0%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```